# Enumerable.Count after Take returns Take-number instead of actual number

Tags: c#, linq, devexpress, xpo

I have a weird situation going on.
I have following query using Devexpress XPO to MS SQL.

```
var _elements = (from n in new XPQuery<Elements>( XpoDefault.Session )
                 select n).Take(100);

int count =  _elements.Count();

foreach ( var e in _elements) {
     Display(e);
);
```

When query has 0 results Count() returns 100, but foreach statement is not executed, because enumerator yield no results.

How can I check how many rows are in query, and take only 100 records (or less)?

I don't understand why `Count()` returns number from take, while there no records to enumerate.

I hope that you can help me.
Thanks!

Comment: What if you add `.ToList()` after the Take(100) ? You are now executing the query twice.

Comment: What is `XPQuery`? Does it support multiple enumerations? Is the foreach loop executed if you remove the previous statement (the one with `Count()` ?

Comment: @ThomasLevesque - I don't know. I can point to documentation, if it help - https://documentation.devexpress.com/#XPO/clsDevExpressXpoXPQuery~T~topic

Comment: @GigaKatowice Can you answer Thomas' second question? "Is the foreach loop executed if you remove the previous statement (the one with `Count()`?" And Hans Kesting's question as well.

Comment: @HansKesting - Creating query with .Take(100).ToList() - returns correct count, and foreach statement is not executed. Acctual query to server is executed only once. When I use only Take(100), there are two queris to the server, one for Count(), and second form Take(100). So probably it is a problem with Devexpress lib.

Comment: @ThomasLevesque - when I remove the line with Count(), the foreach statement is not executed

Comment: @GigaKatowice If the foreach statement is never executed, then the `_elements` simply contains no elements. If that is so, `Take(n).Count()` should always return 0. That seems like a bug in the LINQ provider you're using.

Comment: Is the `Take` in your code the `Enumerable.Take` extension?

Comment: @dcastro, I think it's the `Queryable.Take` extension method, so the implementation depends on the provider. It looks like the provider wrongly assumes that `Take(100)` will always return 100 items.

Comment: @GigaKatowice, I suggest you post your problem to the DevExpress forums, because it looks like a bug in their XPO product.

Comment: @ThomasLevesque my thoughts exactly

Comment: Thank you for help. You are right. Take() is IQueryable.Take. I posted my problem to Devexpress forums. Again, thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check how many rows are in query you need to execute Count() before Take(). Take returns IEnumerable, it means, that query will execute in moment, when you will execute ToList, First/FirstOrDefaut, Last/LastOrDefault etc. [More information about IEnumerable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.collections.ienumerable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: If think you don't understand what is the real problem. I want to know how many records I actually take from database (from 1 to 100 max). The problem is that, Count() after Take() always returns 100.